# SequelizeEagerLoadingError when relationship between models has already been defined

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have an `exports file` that includes all the sequelize-models and then defines the relationship among the models. It looks something like:

```
// Snippet from the global init file

for (let modelFile of modelFileList) {
            // ... Some code ...

            // Require the file
            appliedModels[modelName] = require(`../${MODEL_DIR}/${modelFile}`).call(null, _mysql);
 }

 //Define the relationship between the sql models
 _defineRelationship(appliedModels);


function _defineRelationship(models) {
     models._planAllocationModel.belongsTo(models._subscriptionModel, {
            foreignKey: 'subscription_id',
            targetKey: 'subscription_id'
        });
}
```

But when I try to include the model like:

```
 _subscriptionModel.findAll({
                where: {
                    start_date: {
                        _lte: today // Get all subscriptions where start_date <= today
                    }
                },
                limit,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: _planAllocationModel
                    }
                ]
            });
```

There is an error thrown by sequelize: `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: tbl_plan_allocation is not associated to tbl_subscription_info!` What could be the reason for this? I have already initialized the relationshipt between the 2 models.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The relationship was defined as `belongsTo` which had to be changed to `hasOne` because of the type of `join` applied in the `findAll` query.